# Is there a way to install python libraries from code in app?

Tags: python, installation, pip

Is there a way to install opencv, or any other python libraries without using terminal commands?
I had developed an app in python that works on double click and I want to make it to work for anyone who does not know how to install python libraries. I want to install all my libraries from code.
I've tried this:

```
pip install pip,opencv-python
import cv2
#and a lot of code
```

But I get invalid syntaxError.

Comment: The better approach is probably to install the required libraries when you deliver and install your code. Have a look here, for example: https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/

Answer (score 1):

install packages from a script is by calling pip's command-line interface via a subprocess.

```
import subprocess
import sys

def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do next:

```
import pip


def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, "main"):
        pip.main(["install", package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(["install", package])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    install("opencv-python")
```

Answer (score 0):

how are your users getting your program? if you are using setuptools to create a package, you can add the "install_requires" element and include all of the dependencies. They'll be added to the environment when installed.

```
import setuptools
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="programname",
    version="1.4.0",
    author="Dude",
    author_email="blah@blah",
    description="Some Program",
    long_description=open("readme.md").read(),
    license=open("license.md").read(),
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    url="",
    install_requires=["psycopg2"],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
    ],
)
```